# WCF serviceCertificate appears to be ignoring storeName

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have the following:

```
findValue="10 21 80 7a ec d1 6a 61 9a 4b 44 d8 f4 f6 5d 87 bf 0e 4b fb" 
          x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
          storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="TrustedPeople"/>
```

I am getting related error:

```
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue '10 21 80 7a ec d1 6a 61 9a 4b 44 d8 f4 f6 5d 87 bf 0e 4b fb'.
```

Why is WCF ignoring the storeName and searching My?

Comment: do you have multiple config files? do a global search for `storeName="My"`

Comment: I scoured the config files. Nothing turned up. I can add the cert to the My store and then all works but I would like to get to the bottom of this one.

Comment: i can now only suggest using `X509Store` to get all the certificates to try and debug further.
`var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
                Trace.WriteLine(cert);`
 Use different combinations of arguments, perhaps your cert is ending up in `CurrentUser`

Comment: It is in the TrustedPeople store without a doubt. Why does it need to be in My to be found by WCF?

Comment: no idea. did you try what i wrote above? try running a test process as administrator (or visual studio) to see what results you get